# Using UIDevice - setOrientation will make app rejected?

Tags: ios, ios7, appstore-approval, uiinterfaceorientation

To force portrait, I need to use the following snippet and I wish to learn if by using it, will make the app get rejected from appstore approval?

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"setOrientation:")
```

Comment: No your app wont be rejected but this method is only available till iOS 5.1, For higher versions go with Geet's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use this method?
In your AppDelegate.m:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

It forces the portrait orientation and much safer then anything else.  I used it in one of my apps and it was approved by Apple.